# What is the best way to encrypt a drive on both macOS and Windows?

Tags: macos, windows, encryption

So far I have always encrypted my external drives by formatting them as APFS (Encrypted) with my own passcode. This has worked well since I can access these drives on any macOS installation. However, they are hard to use on Windows; from my research, there is no way to read and write from APFS encrypted drives.

How can I encrypt my external drive in a way that will allow me to access it on Windows?

Comment: Use a common format but encrypt the contents.

Comment: What kind of research have you already done on this?

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not quite sure what you mean—are you talking about individual files? I'm trying to encrypt the whole drive so that no matter what files I put into it, they get encrypted automatically

Comment: Zip file with a password?